# Proving Isomorphism between $G$ and its dual $\hat{G}$

Tags: complex-analysis, group-theory, number-theory, group-isomorphism

I am trying to prove that the homomorphism of $\chi:(\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})^\times \to \mathbb{C}^*$ is an isomorphism, using the definition of Dirichlet characters for $\chi$

I know it has to do with using the fact that $(\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is abelian and can therefore be split into products of cyclic groups, but i get lost there.

Do I use an induction and start with the trivial group first?

Comment: By $(\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})^\times$ do you really mean something like $\prod_{q\in\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})^\times$? Else you have cardinality issues.